# Difference between [ self init ] and self = [ super init ]

Tags: objective-c, ios

I wonder what different between 
`[ self init ]` and `self = [ super init ]` in init family method
if I don't override "init" method.

And why people usually use `self = [ super init ]` in init family method?

Comment: If you got the answer you may accept it. and vote up

Comment: `[self init]` would likely end with a stack overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[ self init ]` means you are initializing the self class.

and

`self = [ super init ]` means initializing super class and the returned address/memory location is set to self class.

Answer (score 0):

people use `self = [ super init ]` to all parent classes up to `NSObject`, so this is very important to do

usually people use  `if (self = [ super init ]) {... return self;}` just in case if `self == nil`, but i've never had such thing

`[self init]` is not right, because you just ignore initialization of parent classes, which might be a cause of bugs

Comment: `[self init]` can be used to call the designated initializer from another initializer. Then the designated initializer itself will call `[super init]` to have the superclass initialize.